# Find the area which is between two curves using Nintegrate

Tags: coding-style

```
    eq1 = (x^2/400) + (y^2/256) == 1;

    eq2 = (x^2/144) - (y^2/289) == 1;

    sl = Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {x, y}]
 
    NIntegrate[eq1 - eq2, {x, s1[1], s1[2]}]
    NIntegrate[eq1 - eq2, {x, s1[2], s1[3]}]
    NIntegrate[eq1 - eq2, {x, s1[3], s1[4]}]
```

Im trying to find the area which is inside the 2 curves. From s1 there are 4 solutions. What i want to do is find the area between solution 1 and 2, then 2 and 3 and then 3 and 4. When I get these values Im going too add it so it will give me the full area which is enclosed inside the two.

BUT its not working and I get zero, why do I get this value?

is there any way of getting a solutions using NIntegrate? I haven't used Implicit function yet

also another thing im trying

```
Clear[f, g, x, y]
f[x_, y_] := (x^2/400) + (y^2/256) == 1;

g[x_, y_] := (x^2/144) - (y^2/289) == 1;
sol = NSolve[f[x, y] == g[x, y], x, y];

{a, b} = x /. sol
{c, d} = y /. sol

Integrate[f[x, y] - g[x, y], {x, a, b}, {y, a, b}]
```

it doesn't work either

Comment: we have to integrate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eq1 = (x^2/400) + (y^2/256) == 1;
eq2 = (x^2/144) - (y^2/289) == 1;

(sl = Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {x, y}]) // N

(* {{x -> -14.3491, y -> -11.1456}, {x -> -14.3491, y -> 11.1456}, {x -> 14.3491,
   y -> -11.1456}, {x -> 14.3491, y -> 11.1456}} *)
```

Assuming that the area of interest is

```
rgn = ImplicitRegion[eq1 && eq2 /. Equal -> LessEqual, {x, y}]

(* ImplicitRegion[x^2/400 + y^2/256 <= 1 && x^2/144 - y^2/289 <= 1, {x, y}] *)

Show[Region[rgn], ContourPlot[Evaluate@{eq1, eq2}, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}],
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[{x, y} /. sl]},
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

```
area = Area[rgn] // Simplify

(* 640 ArcSin[3 Sqrt[545/9529]] + 204 Log[(17721 + 640 Sqrt[545])/9529] *)

area // N

(* 763.394 *)

area == Integrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] rgn] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: I have no idea why, but we've done it slightly differently to each other and ended up with different results. Both our meshes of the regions seem to line up too.

Comment: Area[Point[s1]] and i got undefined

Comment: Points don't have an area, they have a count.  The `RegionMeasure` of the points is `RegionMeasure[Point[{x, y} /. sl]]` which evaluates to `4`